# Eclipse Plugin - XML Editor

Tags: eclipse, plugins, text, editor

I've followed this tutorial:

[Eclipse Plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecca/)

This tutorial explain why create a HTML Editor.

I need a Text editor,just for auto-highlight some words, anyway I thought this tuto should be a good one to start with.

The thing is that I created the **Plugin project** and the only thing that I changed it was the extension "*pat*" instead "*html, htm*", just that. After that I created a .pat file, but eclipse doesn't open it with my plugin, and my text editor is not in the editor's list.

Any suggestion??

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: can give us some more informations? is there any error in the error log? is you plugin in load (you can see that some where in the about menu)?

Comment: I'd say that is not load but , I follow the steps of the tutorial, just that.

Comment: There is no error in the log, because I open the file correctly but in the simple text editor of eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have just created the plugin, but aren't running it in your current Eclipse instance. That can be verified by opening the view "Plugin registry". That will show a list of all plugins, see if the plugin you have created is in that list.

If you click on the run button in Eclipse you will open a run configuration dialog. In one of the tabs, you get to choose what plugins should be available. Make sure your plug-in is selected. This will start up a new Eclipse instance that will run your plugin.

To make your plugin be a part of your ordinary Eclipse installation, you will need to export it to a jar and copy that jar to the dropins catalog.

Comment: Thanks! @Fredrik , you are right, my plugin wasn't selected in the plugin's list.