# Eclipse plugin sample could not be run

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin

On my Mac computer, I follow the tutorial on this page to get [the Taipan example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Modeling_Framework/Tutorial/Part_1) run, but still failed so many times.

> Switch to the Plug-in Development perspective and open the models folder within the org.eclipse.gmf.examples.taipan project. Explore each of the models found hereand their element properties. You'll notice that there are full and RCP versions of the generated Taipan examples to explore.

When I try to run as "Eclipse application", it launches a new eclipse app but the dialog box Examples does not have the 'Taipan Diagram' as it says:

> create an empty project and a new 'TaiPan Diagram' found in the Examples folder of the New dialog

What are the possible causes? Someone helps me to solve it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your plugin is working fine and doesnt show compilation errors?

Then the most likely reason is that you havent chosen your plugin to be active in your launch dialog.
I answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520104/eclipse-plugin-xml-editor/7526121#7526121) with this:

> My guess is that you have just created the plugin, but aren't running it in your current Eclipse instance. That can be verified by opening the view "Plugin registry". That will show a list of all plugins, see if the plugin you have created is in that list.
>
> If you click on the run button in Eclipse you will open a run configuration dialog. In one of the tabs, you get to choose what plugins should be available. Make sure your plug-in is selected. This will start up a new Eclipse instance that will run your plugin.
>
> To make your plugin be a part of your ordinary Eclipse installation, you will need to export it to a jar and copy that jar to the dropins catalog.

Comment: Actually the Taipan plugin sample code got an error while compiling, that's why the Plugin is not installed in the runtime workspace. Thank you for your answer.